# Deliberately offensive(meaning)

Tags: meaning

I've already googled this one [deliberate offence](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Deliberate_offence), BUT, the website is indicating it as a doing in politics/online trolling. On the other hand, I'm putting the exact example here:

> Insulting can be **deliberately offensive** to another student.

Does this mean as:

- very offensive
- or well-executed/very successful attempt of insulting another.

P.S: I think this will be a useful reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you read is for a specialized term.
But your example sentence uses the regular definitions of `deliberate` and `offense`.

[Deliberate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliberate)

> Adj 2: characterized by awareness of the consequences

[Offense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offense)

> Noun 4: the act of displeasing or affronting

So to be 'deliberately offensive' put simply is to **knowingly cause upset on purpose**. It is not praising the insult as being well executed or successful.